# How do I initialize a pointer to an Array of structure

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

```
#define X 10
#define Y 10
```

My structure :

```
typedef struct Reservation {
    char NAME[10];
    int ID;
    int N;
    int RESERVE;
    int POSX;
    int POSY;
} Reservation;
```

My variable declaration :

```
struct Reservation* s[X][Y];
```

i am looking for a way to initialize my variable.

Comment: Your variable `s` is an array size X of array size Y of pointers to Reservation. I.e, it's an array of array of pointers. Is that *really* what you want ?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with doing so? Because the variable declaration was given in the assignement.

Comment: Thanks, And for changing the variables inside on of the structure? I am using : `strcpy(*s[0][0]->NAME, "Lena");`. But it is giving me an unhandled exception at .... Access violation writing location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not pointer to array of structs. It is the array od pointers to struct.

```
#define X 2
#define Y 2

typedef struct Reservation {
    char NAME[10];
    int ID;
    int N;
    int RESERVE;
    int POSX;
    int POSY;
} Reservation;

struct Reservation s1,s2,s3,s4;

struct Reservation a[X][Y] = {{{0,},{0,}},{{0,},{0,}}};

// array of pointers to struct
struct Reservation *s[X][Y] = {&s1, &s2, &s3, &s4};

// pointer to array of structs
struct Reservation (*sa)[X][Y] = &a;
```